# Download data which appears on hover on a webpage using python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the data which appears in the box when i hover on the red dots that appear on the map on this [link](https://datastudio.google.com/embed/u/0/reporting/1PLVi5amcc_R5Gh928gTE8-8r8-fLXJQF/page/R24IB) . I have tried to get the page using selenium python but i cannot get the data which appears on hover. I would like to get the data from all the circles when i hover on them.

i am using this code
i don't know how to get data when hovered

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url ='https://datastudio.google.com/embed/u/0/reporting/1PLVi5amcc_R5Gh928gTE8-8r8-fLXJQF/page/R24IB'
driver.get(url)
source = driver.page_source.encode('UTF-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
```

Comment: Did you forgot to post your code?

Comment: @0m3r i have posted the code